AWS Lambda with SQS FIFO queue trigger maxes out at 1 concurrency
I have an SQS FIFO queue that occasionally gets an influx of messages in the order of tens to hundreds. I set up a Lambda processing function and an SQS trigger with the following parameters:
Lambda concurrency: unreserved (1000)
SQS trigger batch size: 1 (The processing is rather long running, involves connecting to S3 and RDS Postgres database, and takes minutes to complete, so I want a single invocation to process one task, EDIT: while running multiple invocations in parallel, each processing one message.)
SQS trigger maximum concurrency: 10
SQS trigger batch window: 0
My problem is, I never see concurrent executions go above 1 in lambda monitoring. I have read up about how the SQS trigger works by monitoring how busy the queue is and spinning up more polling agents as necessary and while it's not ideal for me, I expected to see more than 1 concurrency after some minutes of the queue being busy and seeing backlogged message counts up to a hundred.
Please give some advice on what I'm not seeing here and which other parameters I should check. My ideal set up would be to see the concurrency max out at 10 as per trigger configuration within about a minute of the queue being busy but for now I want to out least understand why concurrency never goes above a single invocation.
Thanks!

So SQS trigger batch size: 1 triggers one Lambda to be running, since you need it 1 at the time, but still wish to see more than 1 Lambda running?

@Justinas My understanding is that the batch size regulates the amount of messages taken from the queue and sent to a single lambda invocation. My intent is to get multiple (in the current config, up to 10) lambda instances running, each processing a batch of 1 message.

Your understanding of batch size is correct. However, if all your messages have the same message group ID, the FIFO queue will only allow you to retrieve one of them at a time. It won't let you get any more messages of the same message group ID until you delete the last one you retrieved from the queue. This is how it enforces the FIFO pattern.

@MarkB Thank you! I started to suspect the FIFO pattern and it makes so much sense now. I'll just configure the group ID to be random.

If you're going to randomize the group ID for every message then why use FIFO at all?

As jarmod mentioned, it sounds like you don't actually need a FIFO queue.
